Is the following spanning tree problem NP-hard or solvable in polynomial time?
Consider the following combinatorial optimization problem in an undirected weighted graph.
Given:
A connected undirected graph $G = (V, E, w)$ where: $ w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ assigns non-negative weights to the edges.
The problem can be aso seen as a two-stage game between us and an adversary, consisting of the following steps:
First Stage (Our Move):
We select a set of edges $S$, forming a spanning tree in $ G $.
Second Stage (Adversary's Move and Our Response):
The adversary deletes up to 2 edges from $E$. We denote these deleted edges as set $D$. The adversary aims to choose edges to maximize our loss, considering that we may respond in the next step. Note that the adversary can choose any edge in $G$ to delete.
After the adversary's action, we can add up to 1 edge from $ E \setminus D$ to $ (S \setminus D)$. Our added edge $R$  must be chosen such that the resulting edge set $S' = (S \setminus D) \cup R$
still forms a forest. Our goal in this step is to compensate for the loss caused by the adversary's deletion by adding edge that maximize the total weight of the final forest $S' $.
The overall goal is to choose an initial spanning tree $S$ to maximize the minimum total weight of the final forest $ S'$, considering the worst-case action of the adversary and our best possible response.
For example there is a graph consisting of four nodes, with edge weight $ab=3,ad=3,bc=5,cd=8,ac=4$. The optimal $S$ is $ab-bc-ad$. $D$ is $cd$ and $ad$, $R$ is empty set.
Is this problem NP-hard? While we can brute force search for all combinations of deleted and added edges, these depend on the $S$ we choose. And there doesn't seem to be a good way to choose $S$. I'm having trouble trying to give reduction, mainly because it's hard to find similar known NP-hard problems. Any proofs, or references to similar problems are greatly appreciated.

Can you characterize any properties of the optimal $D$?  For instance, must $D$ always be the two heaviest edges of $S$?

optimal $D$ be the 2 edges of $G$(not always in $S$), which causes maximum weight loss to us after we add 1 edge back (So $D$ donot need always to be the two heaviest edge). Since the adversary will consider the effect of our adding edges, there are times when the adversary will delete edges in $G\setminus S$

For example I have a graph consisting of four nodes, with edge weight $ab=3,ad=3,bc=5,cd=8,ac=4$. The optimal $S$ is $ab-bc-ad$. $D$ is $cd$ and $ad$, $R$ is empty set.

Some observations: 1. optimal S are always maximal (because the adversary can also delete edges not in S so there is no advantage of choosing a non-maximal forest S in the first step). 2. We can assume that the graph is connected and thus S is a tree (if not, solve the problem for each connected component individually) 3. For optimal S the adversary always removes at least one edge from S. 4. For unit weights the problem is easy: only bridges and two-cuts of G are relevant.

I don't quite understand your first point where you say that $S$ is always maximal. Look at the example I gave, the optimal $S$ is not a maximal spanning tree (forest)

In your example, $S$ is not maximum but it is maximal (i.e. you cannot add any additional edge to $S$).

Yes I think there must be at least one optimal solution $S$ among all spanning trees. But it still not lead to a polynomial time algorithm.

Are the weights in unary or binary? Moreover (without thinking too much about the problem) if D consists of a single edge then is the problem any easier?

Thinking slightly more I guess it is true that in the |D| = 1 version of the problem, we want to end up with the tree S’ (or forest if D were a cut-edge) of maximum weight in E\D? Thus it makes sense to run max version of Kruskal (in which you sort the edges in non-increasing order and add the ones which do not form a cycle with the previous ones) — so,that the replacement edge is the heaviest edge across the cut formed by deleting D — this is bound to work because the tree thus formed tallies with the heaviest tree in E \ D. The question can be reformulated as: What about |D| <= 2?

I again guess that a similar greedy strategy works for D of size 2 viz. find the maximum spanning tree — now the deletion of any two edges can be (partially) compensated by the heaviest edge across some two of the connected components. I hope I am not missing something important here (like this question being part of a running take home exam ;-)

In fact as long as $|D| \leq |R|$, the maximum spanning tree can provide the optimal S.

I'm not quite sure what greedy strategy you're talking about? If it means that maximum spanning trees are optimal, then the greedy strategy donnot always works. The example I give with 4 nodes already shows this point.

I am a bit confused — if you are referring to the figure in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/169348/how-to-prove-following-weighted-forest-problem-is-np-hard then i don’t see why the heaviest tree containing 4,5,8 weight edges is not the optimal solution. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

The adversary can kill edge 5 and 8, we get final weight of 4+3=7. But If we choose 3,3,5. Then we can have final weight of 8.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

We can prove NP-hardness by embedding an NP-complete selection problem (such as 3-SAT or Subset-Sum) into this two-stage robust spanning-tree framework. We begin by constructing a graph $G=(V,E,w)$ with two types of edges: "indicator edges" of very large weight $M$, each encoding a particular choice (for instance, truth assignment or subset selection), and a network of lower-weight edges that keep the graph connected. If the chosen spanning tree $S$ encodes an invalid solution (e.g., a contradictory set of variable assignments), then there exist two large-weight edges in $S$ whose simultaneous removal (by the adversary) forces the final forest to lose almost all high-weight contribution, because re-adding just one edge cannot recover enough weight to reach some threshold $T$. Conversely, if $S$ represents a valid solution, the adversary's deletion of any two edges cannot prevent us from reinserting at least one high-weight edge and keeping the final total above $T$. Therefore, determining whether there exists an $S$ guaranteeing final weight $\ge T$ is at least as hard as solving the underlying NP-complete problem, so no polynomial-time method exists unless $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$.
A useful way to see why the adversary's optimal deletion set $D$ need not simply be "the two heaviest edges of $S$" is that the adversary is optimizing after anticipating our single-edge addition. In other words, the adversary must consider not only which edges it removes from $S$, but also which edges remain available in $G \setminus D$ for us to add back. In some instances—like the four-node example with edges $ab=3$, $ad=3$, $bc=5$, $cd=8$, $ac=4$ and the chosen tree $S = \{ab,bc,ad\}$—removing the heaviest edge in $S$ ($ad$) together with a certain high-weight edge not in $S$ ($cd$) can cripple our ability to restore a high-weight cycle (e.g., if $cd$ were left intact, we could potentially replace $ad$ by $cd$). Formally, the adversary looks to solve
$$
\max_{D \subseteq E,\, |D|\le 2} \quad \Bigl(\;\underbrace{\sum_{e \in S\setminus D} w(e)}_{\text{tree edges left}} \;+\;\underbrace{\max_{r\in E\setminus D} w(r \text{ is addable})}_{\text{our best response}}\Bigr)^{\!\!\prime\;}
$$
where "$\max(\cdots){\prime}$" indicates the adversary is minimizing our final value. This sometimes requires removing one edge from $S$ (to reduce its current weight) plus one key edge outside $S$ (to prevent us from adding it), rather than simply removing the top two edges of $S$. If one of the "heaviest" edges outside $S$ is left available, we might plug it in and recover a large portion of our total. So whenever there is a potentially large-weight edge in $G \setminus S$ that can be added (forming a cycle or connecting two components after a deletion), the adversary might gain more by removing that edge instead of a second large edge in $S$.

Sorry but I don't really understand the following points in your reduction process: the exact value of $M$, how to construct the graph specifically and how to set the threshold $T$
